# Set of points near zero

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

The subset $A$ of the positive segment of real line has $0$ as a limit point (that is has points of distance less than $\epsilon$ to zero for every positive $\epsilon$).

Let $I(x)$ be an interval containing $x$ for every $x\in A$.

Can we prove that $\bigcup_{x\in A} I(x)$ contains some open interval $]0;z[$ for some $z>0$?

Comment: "The subset A of the positive segment of real line"  I do not know what this means.  Is A itself a segment?  Is A a subset of a segment?  What segment?

Comment: @fleablood $A$ is a set of positive reals, is all that means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer is no.**

---

OPTIMAL COUNTEREXAMPLE: Here's the "right" answer: any set $A$ with $0$ as a limit point, *such that $\mathbb{R}_{>0}\setminus A$ also has $0$ as a limit point*, is a counterexample. This is a good exercise. Moreover, it's the best possible answer: clearly if the complement of $A$ in the positive reals *doesn't* have $0$ as a limit point, then it is *not* a counterexample.

---

ORIGINAL COUNTEREXAMPLE: Consider $A=\{{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, and for ${1\over n}\in A$ let $I({1\over n})$ be the open interval centered around $x$ with radius ${1\over 3n^2+3n}$.

(What's going on: the distance between ${1\over n}$ and ${1\over n+1}$ is $1\over n^2+n$, so as long as the radius of $I({1\over n})$ is appropriately small enough compared to this distance, the intervals won't overlap.)

Comment: Currently no idea how to solve your "good exercise". Please help

Comment: I asked this at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1874854/4876