# Help to prove a claim about real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Noah Schweber [claimed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1874455/4876) that if both a set $A$ of positive numbers and its complement $\mathbb{R}_{>0}\setminus A$ have $0$ as a limit point, then there is such an interval $I(x)$ containing $x$ for every $x\in A$ that for every $z>0$ we have $\bigcup_{x\in A} I(x)$ is not a superset of $]0;z[$ (in other words, the complement of $\bigcup_{x\in A} I(x)$ contains arbitrarily small numbers for some $I$).

Please help me to prove this claim. (Right now not idea how to prove it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be such a set; WLOG let's say $A\subset (0, 1)$. By assumption, we can find a sequence of positive reals $a_i\not\in A$ with

- $a_i>a_{i+1}$ and
- $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}a_i=0$.

Now let $J_0=(a_0, 1)$, $J_{i+1}=(a_{i+1}, a_i)$. Clearly $A\subseteq \bigcup J_i$.

Finally, let $I(x)=J_i$ iff $x\in J_i$, for $x\in A$.

Comment: If I do not err, $\bigcup_{x\in A} I(x) = (0,1)$ in this case and thus is not a counterexample

Comment: Also if $x=a_i$ then $I(x)$ is undefined (I think we should switch to half-open intervals)

Comment: @porton I made a typo - the $a_i$s are supposed to be outside $A$ (so $x\not=a_i$, ever). And the union of the $J_i$s is **not** $(0, 1)$ but rather $(0, 1)\setminus\{a_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: @porton Have I resolved your question?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you ask whether I've understood your proof, then yes

Comment: @porton If so, you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it.